# How to access NancyModule Properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, nancy

In HTML I can access NancyModule properties with help of the Super Simple Engine View (SSVE) like this:

```
<label id="123"> @Model.PropertyName </Label>
```

At runtime @Model.PropertyName will then be replaced by the actual value, which works great. ([More Information about this here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-Super-Simple-View-Engine))

What I am searching is a clean way to access these properties in JavaScript, but I didn't find any solution.

At the moment I load these properties in Labels (or whatever else), hide said Labels and access the properties in JavaScript over these Labels, which is a horrible, but working solution.

Does anyone know a clean and neat solution? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The only way to do this is to either store them in hidden fields etc (like you self suggested) or dynamically generate a javascript block and set javascript variables

Answer (score 0):

One option you have would be to adopt a client side javascript MVVM framework.  There are a lot of frameworks out there to choose from, for instance [KnockoutJs](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Using this approach you'll be able to cleanly orchestrate your client side app without having a mess of events and DOM manipulations.

Here's a basic example, cribbed from KnockoutJs's documentation, that shows how editing a text box automatically updates the view model (again there are many other options).

```js
// Here's my data model.  You can setup using your Nancy model here.
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
  this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
  this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

  this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
  }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.liveExample {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #EEEEDD;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  max-width: 655px;
}
.liveExample input {
  font-family: Arial;
}
.liveExample b {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.liveExample p {
  margin-top: 0.9em;
  margin-bottom: 0.9em;
}
.liveExample select[multiple] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8em;
}
.liveExample h2 {
  margin-top: 0.4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class='liveExample'>
  <p>First name:
    <input data-bind='value: firstName' />
  </p>
  <p>Last name:
    <input data-bind='value: lastName' />
  </p>
  <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just write something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    var 123 = @Model.PropertyName;
</script>
```

Probably your IDE will mark this as wrong, but it works.